# Calculate the sinuoisty of a line

Tags: r, line, sf

I have an sf polyline layer in R an would like to calculate the sinuosity (i.e. actual length of segment divided by the shortest distance between start and endpoint). Does anyone know of a function from sf or similar packages to accomplish this?

Comment: What's an "sf polyline layer"? Do you have an `sf` data frame with a geometry column or a vector of `st_linestring` or `st_multilinestring` object? Have you tried using `st_length` to get the length of linear features, and `st_cast` to convert to points, getting the first and last and using `s_distance` on them?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. No, I have not tried this but it sounds like a good idea thanks!